# String subset match in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Ok I have an autocomplete/string matching problem to solve. I have an expression string typed in by a user into a text box, e.g.

[image]

**More detail:**

Expression textbox has string

> "Buy some Al"

and client has a list of suggestions given by a server after a fuzzy match which populate a listbox

> All Bran, Almonds, Alphabetti Spaghetti

now on the GUI I have a nice intellisense style autocomplete, but I need to wire up the "TAB" action to perform the complete. So if the user presses TAB and "All Bran" was the top suggestion, the string becomes

> "Buy some All Bran"

e.g. the string "Al" was substituted for the top match "All Bran"

It's more than a simple string split on the expression to match the suggestions, as the expression text could be this

> "Buy some All Bran and Al"

with suggestions

> Alphabetti Spaghetti

In which case I'd expect the final Al to be substituted with the top match so the result becomes

> "Buy some All Bran and Alphabetti Spaghetti"

I'm wondering how to do this simply in C# (Just the C# string manipulation, not GUI code) without going back to the server and asking for a substitution to be made.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue - you say the server already returns a list of fuzzy matches - so you already have the data on the client side, why would you need to go looking into the DB again?

Comment: What kind of app is it? Web, Desktop?

Comment: @Charleh I've added an image to clarify. Basically on the client I have the current unfinished expression string, the list of suggestions, but on pressing tab, I need to insert the top suggestion into the expression. 

Jakub - gui technology is Silverlight, I'm just interested in the C# code to do the string substitution though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with regex, but it doesn't seem necessary. The following solution assumes that the suggestion will always be preceded by a space (or start at the beginning of the sentence). If that's not the case then you'll need to share more examples to get the rules down.

```
string sentence = "Buy some Al";
string selection = "All Bran";
Console.WriteLine(AutoComplete(sentence, selection));

sentence = "Al";
Console.WriteLine(AutoComplete(sentence, selection));

sentence = "Buy some All Bran and Al";
selection = "Alphabetti Spaghetti";
Console.WriteLine(AutoComplete(sentence, selection));
```

Here is the `AutoComplete` method:

```
public string AutoComplete(string sentence, string selection)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sentence))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("sentence");
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(selection))
    {
        // alternately, we could return the original sentence
        throw new ArgumentException("selection");
    }

    // TrimEnd might not be needed depending on how your UI / suggestion works
    // but in case the user can add a space at the end, and still have suggestions listed
    // you would want to get the last index of a space prior to any trailing spaces
    int index = sentence.TrimEnd().LastIndexOf(' ');
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return selection;
    }
    return sentence.Substring(0, index + 1) + selection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Join(" and ", suggestions)` to create your replacement string and then `string.Replace()` to do substitution.

Comment: Not sure that'll work - if the user has half typed a suggestion, I need to make the substitution of the partial match with the top-most suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listbox items in the array and while traversing through array, once a match is found, break the loop and get out of it and display the output.